# Can I pack art assets from a leaked source code repository?

Tags: proprietary-code, porting

I am thinking about porting a commercial PlayStation game which had its entire development leaked. This game is SpongeBob SquarePants: SuperSponge. The source code as well as all its development assets were leaked in 2016 after Climax sold quite a bit of their development assets.

The source code is still up at [GitHub](https://github.com/philosophofee/SBSPSS/), and the development discs including the final source code are up at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/sbspdevarchives.7z)

Would it be okay to pack art assets? I'm thinking of making this port open source. If this can't be done, should I just have users supply their copy of the source and compile it their self?

Apologies if this is the wrong place to post this question to.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too sure as this is from a commercial game. This is not decompiled, this is the actual source code.

Comment: Read the linked text again. You have no rights whatsoever, not even downloading for yourself